# JSON for Modern C++ thread safe?

Tags: c++, json, multithreading, github, nlohmann-json

I am using a library named "JSON for Modern C++" (https://github.com/nlohmann/json) which is pretty slick, letting me use JSON configuration files by a C++ program that are shared with a Javascript server side application.  This library essentially creates another datatype that is accessed and manipulated in way that is very close to the same as a Javascript JSON objects.

My question is, do I need to be concerned about thread safety on JSON variable accesses and manipulations or can I trust the library is thread safe.  I've looked in the documentation and I don't see it say it is thread safe but I also don't see anywhere that says it isn't thread safe.

Is anyone else using this library in a multithreaded environment?  Did you need to protect it yourself or did the library protect itself.  Maybe I'm really lucky and the repository author nlohmann will answer directly!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What on earth has json parsing to do with thread safety?

Comment: The question has to do with whether or not the library is thread safe

Comment: How about asking the author? How should we know how they designed it? Asking about 3rd party resources is _off-topic_ BTW.

Comment: Well, if you had used it in a multithreaded environment, you might know it's never given you a problem or that maybe it crashed your application and cost you time and money.  Knowledge of the masses is what SO is all about.  Trying to glean some of that here

Comment: Try mail@nlohmann.me

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, fair game to ask about software tools ie libraries:  What topics can I ask about here?

Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…

a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Comment: Read point #4 from this [help center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for the authors email, I hadn't dug that up yet, emailing him now.  I will post his answer here so others can see if they have same question

Comment: As for point #4, I'm not asking for a recommendation for a library or a tool, just asking if anyone has any relevant experience with a popular library from Github doing multithreading. . .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

nlohmann library is NOT thread safe. Take a look at the header file. It's a single one. There's no mutexes, locks or atomics or anything related to threads.

https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/src/json.hpp

You are responsible for protecting against concurrency of multiple threads accessing this data.

Comment: No need to use any synchronize mechanism if there is not shared resource. For example, an instance of parser class is created with own attributes for each ::parse() call, that seems to be thread-safe for me, no ?

Comment: you are right... you have to tell you what you are targeting as thread safe: Here are are talking about "thread safety on JSON variable accesses", as described in the question.

Comment: and "this data" in my answer.

Comment: nevermind, I suppose 'Brian' should test himself thread safety of this library.

Answer (score 2):

Per the author in [About thread safety #2366](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/discussions/2366):

> No, the container is like a map or a vector: you have to ensure thread safety yourself.